# ExtJS 5: Accessing bound store in component

Tags: javascript, extjs, data-binding, extjs5

I'm having a real hard time understanding how to access the actual bound store instance on a component, like a ComboBox or Grid. It appears that when you use their getStore method, it returns a different instance.

In my [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/sr3), I have a custom grid class, and in its initComponent, I want to add a load listener. Unfortunately, the load listener never gets hit, but the bound store's load listener does.  You can see the listener is getting set up before the store is loaded, so that's not the issue.  It looks like the store instance in initComponent is a memory store, so the bound store's instance is not synced to the component at this point.

I know I can have a load listener on the bound store, but this is a custom grid class, and for any custom grid class, I want there to be a listener set up... so I don't want to have to do this all over the place in my code... I just want it in one class, as they're all going to have the same logic carried out.

Can someone explain to me why my custom grid class's load listener is not getting hit, and what can I do to fix this? Can I somehow access the bound store instance?

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyGrid', {
      extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
      xtype: 'myGrid',
      initComponent: function() {
        alert('initComponent')
        this.callParent();
        this.getStore().on('load', this.onLoad, this);
      },
      onLoad: function() {
        alert('grid store loaded');
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyViewController', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
      alias: 'controller.myview',
      onLoadBoundStore: function() {
        alert('loaded bound');
      }
    })
    Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
      alias: 'viewmodel.myview',
      stores: {
        myStore: {
          fields: ['name', 'value'],
          autoLoad: true,
          proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data1.json',
            reader: {
              type: 'json'
            }
          },
          listeners: {
            load: 'onLoadBoundStore'
          }
        }
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyView', {
      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      controller: 'myview',
      viewModel: {
        type: 'myview'
      },
      items: [{
        title: 'blah',
        xtype: 'myGrid',
        reference: 'myComboBox',
        bind: {
          store: '{myStore}'
        },
        columns: [{
          text: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
          text: 'Value',
          dataIndex: 'value'
        }]
      }]
    });
    Ext.create('MyView')
  }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why my custom grid class's load listener is
>   not getting hit, and what can I do to fix this?

You are not initially providing any store to your grid (the [`store`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-store) config option is *required* by the way). Hence the grid is creating its own, empty store as coded [here](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/Table2.html#Ext-panel-Table-method-initComponent):

```
store = me.store = Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup(me.store || 'ext-empty-store');
```

That empty store is the one that gets your `onLoad` listener attached. It is not getting hit because the store is never loaded.

> Can I somehow access
>   the bound store instance?

Yes, use this:

```
this.lookupViewModel().getStore('myStore')
```

You can attach your listener to the bound store instead of the empty one and see the difference. The grid's empty store eventually gets replaced by the bound one (this is why you see data in the grid, after all), but this happens *after* `initComponent` is executed. You can track the moment of setting the bound store to the grid by overriding `setStore` method.

> I know I can have a load listener on the bound store, but this is a
>   custom grid class, and for any custom grid class, I want there to be a
>   listener set up... so I don't want to have to do this all over the
>   place in my code... I just want it in one class, as they're all going
>   to have the same logic carried out.

Since you are using MVVC it is recommended to stick to the pattern and keep views declaring view aspects only. Listeners should be declared and handled in controllers (not even in viewmodels like in your example). Otherwise, if you continue sticking to pre Ext JS 5 style and put dynamic stuff in views (i.e. the grid in your case) there is no point in using MVVC.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much!  You have given me a couple more follow-up questions... `the store config option is required by the way` right, but I'm binding a store, so do you actually declare a store even if you're binding one?  That seems redundant.

Comment: `Listeners should be declared and handled in controllers (not even in viewmodels like in your example).`  So by this logic, you're saying I shouldn't be declaring listeners in the view either?  I think that adds way too much bloat in the controller... then I have to lookup all of the references and add the listeners... that seems a bit unnecessary, considering I have a convenient way of adding listeners.

Comment: `this.lookupViewModel()` is a very interesting piece of knowledge... considering `this.getViewModel()` returns null.  Looks like the latter is a convenient getter for the current level viewModel, and then lookupViewModel goes until it finds one, which would be the inherited one.

Comment: Re binding store and providing store config at the same time — yes it's redundant, but if you don't do the latter then empty store will be unnecessarily created. I'm not sure what the recommended practice here is. Where did you see that store can be bound via viewmodel? Perhaps answer is there... *I think that adds way too much bloat in the controller* Well, then ask yourself why are you using controllers at all if adding listeners within views is *convenient*? If engaging controllers, I'd delegate them all job they are supposed to do. This is all matter of taste until the day it costs you $.

Comment: Well controllers contain the actual handler logic, and the reason why I use a controller is because it then corrals the View Model and View listeners into one centralized location, which is how it's supposed to be done... plus, I create and use getters in the controller, so it's much easier to carry out the handler logic this way.  I agree though about it costing me one day... this is still very new to me, so I'm trying to figure out best practices, which don't seem clearly defined, as per most JS development.

Comment: Just thought: you can put `this.store = this.lookupViewModel().getStore('myStore');` before `this.callParent()`. That would both prevent the creation of empty store and make your example work as expected.

Comment: The only problem with this entire solution is that not all of my stores are called `myStore` (they all have different names).  I don't think there's much I can do here, so I guess I'll have to go back to the drawing boards... very helpful answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is so incredibly hacky that I don't even want to post it as an answer, but I'm going to just for posterity sake.  Building on Drake's answer, I figured out how to get my store using what was passed in the initial config of my grid class.  The bind comes in with the braces, so that's why I'm doing a `replace` on it.  Like I said, this probably should never be used, but it's something.

```
initComponent: function() {
  var store = this.lookupViewModel().getStore(this.config.bind.store.replace(/[{}]/g, ''));
  store.on('load', this.onLoad, this);
  this.callParent();
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add one more option to the mix, you can listen to the [`reconfigure`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-reconfigure) event on the grid, as that's what fires after binding a store is complete... so something like this would work:

```
Ext.application({
  name: 'Fiddle',

  launch: function() {
    Ext.define('MyGrid', {
      extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
      xtype: 'myGrid',
      initComponent: function() {
        alert('initComponent')
        this.on('reconfigure', this.onReconfigureGrid, this);
        this.callParent();
      },
      onReconfigureGrid: function(grid, store, columns, oldStore, oldColumns, eOpts) {
        store.on('load', this.onLoad, this);
      },
      onLoad: function() {
        alert('grid store loaded');
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyViewController', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
      alias: 'controller.myview',
      onLoadBoundStore: function() {
        alert('loaded bound');
      }
    })
    Ext.define('MyViewModel', {
      extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
      alias: 'viewmodel.myview',
      stores: {
        myStore: {
          fields: ['name', 'value'],
          autoLoad: true,
          proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'data1.json',
            reader: {
              type: 'json'
            }
          },
          listeners: {
            load: 'onLoadBoundStore'
          }
        }
      }
    });
    Ext.define('MyView', {
      extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
      renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
      controller: 'myview',
      viewModel: {
        type: 'myview'
      },
      items: [{
        title: 'blah',
        xtype: 'myGrid',
        reference: 'myComboBox',
        bind: {
          store: '{myStore}'
        },
        columns: [{
          text: 'Name',
          dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
          text: 'Value',
          dataIndex: 'value'
        }]
      }]
    });
    Ext.create('MyView');
  }
});
```